# Can I use a phone number instead of a Sender ID when sending SMS with Amazon SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am integrating AWS SNS into a project which sends transactional sms messages on a daily basis. Currently I have it working with SenderID in Germany and Sweden but I noticed that when I send to a US number it shows a phone number. This is expected according to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html):

> Support for sender IDs varies by country and/or region. For example, messages delivered to U.S. phone numbers will not display the sender ID.

This is not a problem. However, it would be easier if I could configure my SMS messages to always show a phone number and not a Sender ID as the sender.

**Is it possible to configure AWS SNS to send SMS messages with a phone number as a sender instead of the Sender ID for all countries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (i.e as of 06th April 2020) Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) doesn't support using phone number commonly known as **Long Code** in place of **Sender ID**.

I would like to refer you to another AWS service called [Amazon Pinpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-originating-identities.html) which I know supports the use Long Code.